# Do people say widespread influence?

Tags: idioms

Is widespread influence grammatically correct? Also, is it the right way to say it? Thanks

Comment: *Widespread* is an adjective, and *influence* is a noun, so it's grammatically correct. But there might be right and wrong ways to use it. Can you give a sentence you want to use it in?

Comment: The widespread influence of the company raised nationwide consciousness.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, **widespread influence** is a [common phrase](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=widespread%20influence).